# msbuild seems to fail on preprocessors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a couple of projects in one solution. One project (project_UWP) is the "startup"-project which depends on the other projects. Building the solution and running `project_UWP` works fine under Visual Studio.

There is one project in the solution though, let's call it `3dParty_Project` which contains a file `3dParty_Helper.cs`. I cannot share the file (legal reasons), but this file contains a lot of parts like:

```
#if !Xamarin
// Do stuff..
#else
// Do some other stuff
#endif
```

Like I mentioned before If I build `project_UWP` which depends on `3dParty_Project` all the dependencies in the solution are built successfully and I can run my application. On my build server I am using MSBuild though.

```
msbuild project_UWP.csproj /t:clean;build /p:RunCodeAnalysis=False /maxcpucount:1
```

In this case I am getting an error in the `3dParty_Helper.cs`:

> ... error CS1513: } expected ...

As the projects are built fine in Visual Studio I suspect that msbuild somehow overwrites the 'Conditional compilation symbols' for dependency projects while building. I am using msbuild from:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

The Compilation symbols in `project_UWP` are:

> NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS

The compilation symbols in `3dParty_Project` are:

> XForms;Xamarin

I assume that the compilation symbols are the source for the error because looking at `3dParty_Helper.cs` I can not see any parts where a `}` is missing. That is why I think that at some point there is a problem with parts like:

```
#if WPF || Android || IOS || WF
if (/* stuff */)
{
    // do stuff
}
else if (/* other stuff */)
#endif
    // define stuff
#if !WinRT && !XForms
else
    // Do some magic
#endif
```

How could I approach this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that your MSBuild command is running a different build configuration than you normally do in Visual Studio?

Comment: @JoeSewell doesn't it use the definitions in `.csproj` on default?

Comment: Yes, but the definitions can be configuration-specific (e.g., just for `Debug`, or just for `Release`). Does the `PropertyGroup` tag that contains your `DefineConstants` tag have a `Condition` attribute?

Comment: Yes it does, actually for every `<PropertyGroup>`: i. e.: `Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'"`

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you're building in the `Release` configuration in Visual Studio, so try explicitly specifying the configuration in MSBuild with `/p:Configuration=Release` on the command line.

Comment: @JoeSewell I already tried that to no avail, for both `Debug` and `Release`.

Comment: Have you tried build the `3dParty_Project` with msbuild command line first, then build `project_UWP`, check if you still have this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Yes I did, same result.

Comment: @indexoutofbounds, Thank you for your quick reply. It seems that it is not easy to reproduce this issue, due to you can not share the file, would you reproduce this issue with simple sample so that we could analyze this issue? Thanks.